# Crear tabla si no existe en la BD con un trigger ORACLE SQL

Tags: oracle

como dice el enunciado necesito un trigger que se dispare luego de insertar un registro en una tabla "tabla0". Si la tabla1 no existe este trigger debe crearla y luego realizar el insert. Tenia pensado algo así:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRG_INSERT_HISTORIAL
AFTER INSERT ON tabla0
BEGIN
IF INSERTING THEN
  IF NOT EXISTS (tabla1)  THEN
    CREATE TABLE tabla1 (...);      

ELSE
   INSERT INTO TABLA1 VALUES (...);
END IF;
END;
```

Pero no se bien la sentencia del "SI NO EXISTE LA TABLA1" entonces crearla y insetar "datos" a dicha tabla. Espero una ayudita, gracias!

Comment: las base de datos relacionales no fueron creadas para eso, si piensas hacer algo como lo que hablas te recomiendo NOSQL

Comment: gracias por el consejo estimado lo tendré en cuenta!

Answer (score 0):

Para hacer lo que estás necesitando, necesitas [usar **SQL DINÁMICO**](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96590/adg09dyn.htm) dentro de PL/SQL. No sé si es lo más recomendable, pero definitivamente, si quieres hacerlo, lo puedes realizar:

```
BEGIN
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'create table foo (a char(1))';
END;
/
```

Concretamente, lo que quieres hacer se podría con algo así:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRG_INSERT_HISTORIAL
AFTER INSERT ON tabla0
DECLARE
   v_Cnt number;
BEGIN
  IF INSERTING THEN
    select count(1) into v_Cnt
      from user_tables
     where tablename = 'tabla1';
    if v_Cnt = 0 then -- la tabla no existe
       execute immediate 'CREATE TABLE tabla1 (a char(1), b date, c number)';
    end if;
    execute immediate 'insert into tabla1 values (''a'', sysdate, 1)';
  END;
END;
```

Comment: estimado, lo hice pero me lanza un error al insertar un registro para que se desencadene el trigger.. ORA-04092: cannot COMMIT in a trigger, que podrá ser?